# OAuthWebSecurity "Remember me" for Twitter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, twitter-oauth, dotnetopenauth

Using DotNetOpenAuth on MVC4 C# for my application to get authentication for users from Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and yahoo. Currently all the providers other than twitter will allow existing users to just log in without asking for permission when coming back to the site.

I noticed that Twitter has a "Remember me" check box on permission request on their page. Even if I select it, it still asks me next time for my twitter username and password. The other three providers automatically authenticate me without seeing their sign in page.

How to get users coming back to my site through Twitter log in to not go through permission request again?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is because Twitter requires you to be signed in to Twitter.

Saying it the other way around, the "remember me" button remembers that a user has authorized Twitter to share their user data with your website and that they accept to use their account to log in to your website the next time. But you still have to be logged in to Twitter to be authorised for the particular session.

So when a user is already signed into Twitter, they don't need to sign in for your website when the "remember me" check box has been checked.

Also see the [developer documentation - sign in flow](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/browser-sign-flow) saying:

> Twitter keeps track of the authorizations, so for users already signed in to twitter.com who have authorized the application, no UI is shown - instead, they are automatically redirected back to the application.

and

> In the case where the user is already signed in to twitter.com and has granted access to the website, this redirect happens immediately.

Comment: My issue is that even if logged in to Twitter I'm still required to enter my credentials to authenticate into my site. So the problem might possibly be not with the "remember me" but rather returning user authentication through Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this question and the answer about the specific interaction between DNOA and Twitter

[MVC4's DotNetOpenAuth TwitterClient sample does not respect prior login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034084/mvc4s-dotnetopenauth-twitterclient-sample-does-not-respect-prior-login)