# MVC4's DotNetOpenAuth TwitterClient sample does not respect prior login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-oauth, dotnetopenauth

If I create an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application using the `Internet Application` template, it pre-installs all the components and configuration necessary to implement authentication using a range of OAuth and OpenID providers. Just adding my Twitter consumer key and secret to `AuthConfig.cs` activates authentication via Twitter.

However, it doesn't seem to work as I would expect.

If I attempt to authenticate using Twitter, it invariably displays a Twitter sign-on page, regardless of whether I am already signed on to Twitter. It also logs me out of Twitter, so that I am forced to re-authenticate on my next browser visit to Twitter.

Is this a bug, or is some additional configuration necessary to transform this into the more usual seamless workflow (which is working correctly for other providers like Google)?

Thanks, in advance.

Tim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case anyone else comes up against this issue, I'll present here what I have discovered (together with a rather ugly workaround).

Using Fiddler to examine the HTTP traffic between `DotNetOpenAuth` and Twitter, it is clear that the authentication request contains the `force_login=false` querystring parameter, which suggests that DNOA is working correctly. However, if I use Fiddler's scripting capability to modify the outbound request and remove the `force_login` parameter altogether, everything starts working correctly. I am guessing that Twitter's implementation is at fault here, by treating the presence of any `force_login` parameter as being equivalent to `force_login=true`.

Since I don't imagine it will be possible to get Twitter to modify the behavior of their API, I have investigated whether there is a more accessible solution.

Looking at the DNOA code, I see that the `force_login=false` parameter is unconditionally added to the HTTP request by the `DotNetOpenAuthWebConsumer.RequestAuthentication()` method (and subsequently modified to `true` when required).

So, the ideal solution would be for DNOA to offer finer-grained control over its authentication request parameters and for `TwitterClient` to explicitly remove the `force_login=false` parameter. Unfortunately, the current DNOA codebase doesn't directly support this, but it is possible to achieve the same effect by creating two custom classes.

The first is a custom implementation of `IOAuthWebWorker` which is a direct copy of the original `DotNetOpenAuthWebConsumer` class, apart from a single-line change that initializes the redirect parameter dictionary as an empty dictionary:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients;
using DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Messages;

namespace CustomDotNetOpenAuth
{
    public class CustomDotNetOpenAuthWebConsumer : IOAuthWebWorker, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly WebConsumer _webConsumer;

        public CustomDotNetOpenAuthWebConsumer(ServiceProviderDescription serviceDescription, IConsumerTokenManager tokenManager)
        {
            if (serviceDescription == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceDescription");
            if (tokenManager == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("tokenManager");

            _webConsumer = new WebConsumer(serviceDescription, tokenManager);
        }

        public HttpWebRequest PrepareAuthorizedRequest(MessageReceivingEndpoint profileEndpoint, string accessToken)
        {
            return _webConsumer.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(profileEndpoint, accessToken);
        }

        public AuthorizedTokenResponse ProcessUserAuthorization()
        {
            return _webConsumer.ProcessUserAuthorization();
        }

        public void RequestAuthentication(Uri callback)
        {
            var redirectParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var request = _webConsumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(callback, null, redirectParameters);

            _webConsumer.Channel.PrepareResponse(request).Send();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _webConsumer.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other requirement is a custom `OAuthClient` class, based on the original `TwitterClient` class. Note that this requires a little more code than the original `TwitterClient` class, as it also needs to replicate a couple of methods that are internal to the DNOA base class or other utility classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients;
using DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Messages;

namespace CustomDotNetOpenAuth
{
    public class CustomTwitterClient : OAuthClient
    {
        private static readonly string[] UriRfc3986CharsToEscape = new[] { "!", "*", "'", "(", ")" };

        public static readonly ServiceProviderDescription TwitterServiceDescription = new ServiceProviderDescription
        {
            RequestTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            UserAuthorizationEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            AccessTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            TamperProtectionElements = new ITamperProtectionChannelBindingElement[] { new HmacSha1SigningBindingElement() },
        };

        public CustomTwitterClient(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret)
            : this(consumerKey, consumerSecret, new AuthenticationOnlyCookieOAuthTokenManager())
        {
        }

        public CustomTwitterClient(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, IOAuthTokenManager tokenManager)
            : base("twitter", new CustomDotNetOpenAuthWebConsumer(TwitterServiceDescription, new SimpleConsumerTokenManager(consumerKey, consumerSecret, tokenManager)))
        {
        }

        protected override AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthenticationCore(AuthorizedTokenResponse response)
        {
            var accessToken = response.AccessToken;
            var userId = response.ExtraData["user_id"];
            var userName = response.ExtraData["screen_name"];

            var profileRequestUrl = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?user_id=" + EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(userId));
            var profileEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(profileRequestUrl, HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest);
            var request = WebWorker.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(profileEndpoint, accessToken);

            var extraData = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "accesstoken", accessToken } };

            try
            {
                using (var profileResponse = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var responseStream = profileResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        var document = xLoadXDocumentFromStream(responseStream);

                        AddDataIfNotEmpty(extraData, document, "name");
                        AddDataIfNotEmpty(extraData, document, "location");
                        AddDataIfNotEmpty(extraData, document, "description");
                        AddDataIfNotEmpty(extraData, document, "url");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // At this point, the authentication is already successful. Here we are just trying to get additional data if we can. If it fails, no problem.
            }

            return new AuthenticationResult(true, ProviderName, userId, userName, extraData);
        }

        private static XDocument xLoadXDocumentFromStream(Stream stream)
        {
            const int maxChars = 0x10000; // 64k

            var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
                {
                MaxCharactersInDocument = maxChars
            };

            return XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(stream, settings));
        }

        private static void AddDataIfNotEmpty(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, XDocument document, string elementName)
        {
            var element = document.Root.Element(elementName);

            if (element != null)
            {
                AddItemIfNotEmpty(dictionary, elementName, element.Value);
            }
        }

        private static void AddItemIfNotEmpty(IDictionary<string, string> dictionary, string key, string value)
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                dictionary[key] = value;
            }
        }

        private static string EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(string value)
        {
            var escaped = new StringBuilder(Uri.EscapeDataString(value));

            for (var i = 0; i < UriRfc3986CharsToEscape.Length; i++)
            {
                escaped.Replace(UriRfc3986CharsToEscape[i], Uri.HexEscape(UriRfc3986CharsToEscape[i][0]));
            }

            return escaped.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Having created these two custom classes, implementation simply entails registering an instance of the new `CustomTwitterClient` class in the MVC4 `AuthConfig.cs` file:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new CustomTwitterClient("myTwitterApiKey", "myTwitterApiSecret"));
```